# Convert VNC RFB Frame data into Image in Python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, python-imaging-library, scikit-image

I am currently trying to take frame buffer updates from the RFB protocol (VNC Connection) and convert the 32-bit RAW's (string of byte data) into a picture using Python's Pillow or scikit-image (numpy)  I can currently do it with PyQt4:

```
picture = PyQt4.QtGui.QImage(width, height, PyQt4.QtGui,QImage.Format_RGB32)
box = PyQt4.QtGui.QImage(box_w, box_h, PyQt4.QtGui,QImage.Format_RGB32)
with PyQt4.QtGui.QPainter(picture) as qp:
    qp.drawImage(x, y, box, 0, 0, x_val, y_val)
```

However, I don't want to bring in the PyQt4 library just to perform this.  How can I do the same thing using either Pillow or scikit-image (w/ numpy)?

I have tried using Image.frombuffer() using raw decoder and reading the bytes directly into a ndarray; however when I save the resulting object/array without any manipulation I can see that it didn't take in the bytes correctly.

Comment: How? Read the documentation.

Comment: I don't know in which format you have access to this data, but it sounds like you should be able to view it directly as a numpy array.

Comment: I thought I could place it into a ndarray directly as well, but taking in the bytes and reading it into the array does not render the picture correctly.  (I know by saving the array into pic and seeing what the resulting picture was)

Answer (score 0):

I assume your '32-bit RAW' picture is just a buffer of bytes in which each quadruplet represents a pixel in R,G,B,A format. You could create a Pillow image from it using the code below.  I use the **array** module to create an example input memmory buffer.

```
from PIL import Image
import array

# Raw bytes representing a 2x2 image.
rawdata = array.array("B", (255, 0, 0, 255,    0, 255, 0, 255,
                            0, 0, 255, 255,  255, 255, 0, 255))

# Make a pillow image from the raw bytes.
im = Image.frombytes("RGBA", (2, 2), rawdata)
im.show()
im.save("test.png")
```